# How to reference Timezone (TZ) from a separate column?

Tags: r

I am attempting to assign the correct timezone (TZ) for each observation in my dataset (Attached screenshot). I have successfully been able to mutate the TZ columns (Start_TimeZone) to new columns (Start_TimeZone_New) to represent the "normal" TZ designations (i.e. "America/Los_Angeles"). The issue I am running into, is understanding how to assign this new TZ column to each date/time observation (2nd code snippet). The ultimate goal is to utilize the TZ assignment to calculate the duration between start and end date/time (end date/time not shown).

[image: Start Date/Time Example]

[image]

````
```
comp_report_tz %>% 
mutate(Start_TimeZone_New = case_when(is.na(Start_TimeZone) ~ "missing",
           Start_TimeZone == "-08:00" ~ "America/Los_Angeles",
           Start_TimeZone == "-07:00" ~ "America/Phoenix",
           Start_TimeZone == "-06:00" ~ "America/Chicago",
           Start_TimeZone == "-05:00" ~ "America/New_York",
                                       TRUE ~ "others")) %>% 
mutate(End_TimeZone_New = case_when(is.na(End_TimeZone) ~ "missing",
           Start_TimeZone == "-08:00" ~ "America/Los_Angeles",
           Start_TimeZone == "-07:00" ~ "America/Phoenix",
           Start_TimeZone == "-06:00" ~ "America/Chicago",
           Start_TimeZone == "-05:00" ~ "America/New_York",
                                       TRUE ~ "others"))
```

``` 
comp_report_adj %>% 
mutate(Start_Time_Final = as.POSIXct(comp_report_tz$Start_Date_Time, format = "%m/%d/%y 
%I:%M%p", tz=comp_report_adj$Start_TimeZone_New)
```
````

Comment: Can you change all the timezones to UTC? It will be easy to get the difference of time then.

Comment: This is a good idea. I will test this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub_final_report <- comp_report_adj %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Start_Date_Time2 = ymd_hms(Start_Date_Time, tz = Start_TimeZone_New)) %>% 
  mutate(End_Date_Time2 = ymd_hms(End_Date_Time, tz = End_TimeZone_New))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some functions in the R package `lubridate` that might help.

```
library(magrittr)
library(lubridate)

assign_tz <- function(dt, tz){
  lubridate::tz(dt) <- tz
  return(dt)
}

tibble::tibble(end = lubridate::now(tz = "America/New_York"), tz_end = "America/New_York", 
               start = lubridate::as_datetime("2018-01-01", tz = "America/Chicago"), tz_start = "America/New_York"
               ) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(start_tz = assign_tz(start, tz_start), end_tz = assign_tz(end, tz_end), diff = end_tz - start_tz)
```

Since your `Start_Date_Time` and your end date times have timezones associated with them, you should be able to calculate the duration as above, by subtracting the start datetime from the end datetime.

Comment: My issue with this is that, yes the TZ is associated with each start date/time and end date/time observation but is not part of the actual start date/time column (record). Unless I am misunderstanding, I can't simply state tz = "America/New_York" because each observation has a different TZ associated.

Comment: Why is it problematic for every value to have its own time zone? When subtracting times, time zone is accounted for.

Comment: I'm not sure that I'm understanding your question. How did you get the data into the structure that you present above, where you have three columns? If you omit columns 2 and 3, do you still know the time zone for each date time in column 1? In other words, is the time zone "hidden" because of the way that you present column 1 entries?

Comment: If I omit columns 2 and 3, I will not know what the time zone is for each date in column 1.

Comment: Why is that? How did you create the object that you shared above?

Comment: Create which object, "Start_TimeZone_New"? I was able to create this object by mutating Start_TimeZone (column 2). The data is coming from a csv file and the timezone is predetermined as Start_TimeZone (column 2).

Comment: I was trying to refer to the dataframe that you display.

Comment: The 2 screenshots are of separate columns (3) in the same data frame.

Comment: Thanks. I edited my code to, I think, do what you need. Does it work? Does it make sense?

Comment: I know this is very late, but I was finally able to solve it using rowise()